# Use of a broken or risky cryptographic algorithm encryption algorithm. base64EncodedString should not be used

Tags: swift, xcode, security, owasp

I'm running a security code analysis with Kiuwan on one of my Swift libs and I got one issue marked as hight vulnerability that says exactly what the title read and it's point me out this portion of my code:

```
53 public let data: Data

54 public var base64String: String {
55    return data.base64EncodedString()
56 }
```

The line 55 to be precise, witch is the Swift built in base64 string encoder from `Data`

Any Idea of what can I do in order to fix that vulnerability ?

Comment: The message does not make sense at all because base64 is neither a cryptographic nor an encryption algorithm. May be you have copied the wrong code part? Check where `base64String` is used in relation to encryption. There should be the problem located.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I double checked and no that function was not meant to cypher or something it's just to get a representation of an already cypher key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are NOT doing encryption (wanting to perserve the confidentiality and integrity of data) then you have a false positive here. Static code analyser tools meant for security scanning are generating false positives in huge amounts. You need to dig through, understand the context and decide whether it is a bug or not yourself.

If you are doing encryption here, then it is obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes I'll go with that you said, it seems to be a false positive, thanks man